# Does this wiring pattern for a DB9 cable exist as a standard cable?

Tags: communication, rs232, db9

I have a scientific instrument that uses a DB9 cable to connect to the standard RS232 port on a computer for communication. I've deconstructed one of the cables as I needed to make another one but I am wondering if this wiring pattern is a standard wiring variation seen with DB9 cables or if it is completely proprietary. I don't want to have to make these cables if I don't have to.

[image: DB9 Wiring Diagram]

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for products get closed here. Can I suggest that you reword your question to ask for a solution to the problem rather than a recommendation for a product.

Comment: It's more about identifying this particular [pinout](http://i1.wp.com/wiki.amigaos.net/w/images/thumb/7/74/05-db9-db9.png/800px-05-db9-db9.png?resize\u003d450300) than about where to buy it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a standard `null modem cable with handshake` also known as `crossover`.

It is used to  connect two DCE devices or two DTE devices together.

DCE (data circuit-terminating equipment)  .... example: modem
DTE (data terminal equipment)  .................... example: computer

[image]

```
TXD - transmit data
RXD - receive data
RTS - request to send   
CTS - clear to send
DTR - data terminal ready
DSR - data set ready
```

Comment: With **both** DTR/DSR and CTS/RTS handshake. There are cables without one or the other handshake in the wild.

Comment: Thank god I don't have to make any more.